# How can I sub-select data by `id` and `date` from another query output?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery

I used the following PostgreSQL query:

```
select ufvs.pipedrive_id as pipe_id, 
  il.created_at as "date", 
  il.inverter_id as inverter_id, 
  il.dca as dca, il.dcv as dcv
from ufvs 
inner join inverter_ufv 
  on ufvs.id = inverter_ufv.ufv_id 
inner join inverter_logs il 
  on inverter_ufv.inverter_id = il.inverter_id
order by pipe_id, "date", inverter_id;
```

Each `pipe_id` may be associated to 1 or more `inverter_id` values. For example, `pipe_id` = 1 is associated to more than 10 `inverter_id` values. Column `"date"` is in datetime format.

I got this output:

[image]

However, this query output is huge (more than 13 million rows) and therefore, it is very hard to export it as .csv and work with it on python as a pandas dataframe. I need to sub-select the data from that output: I only want data from the first 5 days and last 5 days ("date") of each "inverter_id".

What am I missing in my original PostgreSQL query?

The current code:

```
with
    t1 as (
        select
            min(il.created_at) min_date,
            max(il.created_at) max_date,
            ufvs.pipedrive_id
        from
            ufvs
            inner join inverter_ufv on ufvs.id = inverter_ufv.ufv_id
            inner join inverter_logs il on inverter_ufv.inverter_id = il.inverter_id
        group by ufvs.pipedrive_id
    )
select
    ufvs.pipedrive_id as pipe_id,
    il.created_at as "date",
    il.inverter_id as inverter_id,
    il.dca as dca,
    il.dcv as dcv
from
    ufvs
    inner join inverter_ufv on ufvs.id = inverter_ufv.ufv_id
    inner join inverter_logs il on inverter_ufv.inverter_id = il.inverter_id
    inner join t1 on (
        t1.pipedrive_id = ufvs.pipedrive_id
        and (
            il.created_at between t1.min_date and t1.min_date + 5
            or il.created_at between t1.max_date - 5 and t1.max_date
        )
    )
order by
    pipe_id,
    "date",
    inverter_id;
```

that produces the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 832

Error position: line: 35 pos: 831
```

I changed the "date" column format to "YYYY-mm-dd" but still get the same error 42883.

Comment: Use a CTE to determine the min(date) and max(date) for each inverter id. Then join to the CTE on ID, and in your where clause add your datediff restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
with
    t1 as (
        select
            min(il.created_at) min_date,
            max(il.created_at) max_date,
            ufvs.pipedrive_id
        from
            ufvs
            inner join inverter_ufv on ufvs.id = inverter_ufv.ufv_id
            inner join inverter_logs il on inverter_ufv.inverter_id = il.inverter_id
        group by ufvs.pipedrive_id
    )
select
    ufvs.pipedrive_id as pipe_id,
    il.created_at as "date",
    il.inverter_id as inverter_id,
    il.dca as dca,
    il.dcv as dcv
from
    ufvs
    inner join inverter_ufv on ufvs.id = inverter_ufv.ufv_id
    inner join inverter_logs il on inverter_ufv.inverter_id = il.inverter_id
    inner join t1 on (
        t1.pipedrive_id = ufvs.pipedrive_id
        and (
            il.created_at between t1.min_date and DATE_ADD(t1.min_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
            or il.created_at between DATE_SUB(t1.max_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY) and t1.max_date
        )
    )
order by
    pipe_id,
    "date",
    inverter_id;
```

Here CTE `t1` contains min and max dates of creation, and later it joined to initial query to filter by date.

Comment: Hi @markalex, I could successfully implement the query with just a few small variations from the code proposed by your answer. Anyways, I believe the credit is yours. Thank you!